# What is difference between application context and spring context?

Tags: spring, javabeans

I know what is application Context. It is an interface which provides spring beans. Could you please explain what is spring Context and what is the difference between two?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

They are the same things, we just use 2 differents words.

The `Application Context` is, **programmatically speaking**, an interface giving you access to your bean, like you said.

**Conceptually speaking**, it is a black box, where you can't enter, and Spring uses it to store everything it knows about your application. If you declared beans, they will be in there. Every object of your application that Spring manages are in there.

There is no such thing as `Spring context`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring context is a [jar file](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-context/latest/index.html) (module name) in which `ApplicationContext` class resides.